# Why is the while loop not working in the if loop?

Tags: python

```
    def n():
        name = input('What is the missing animal?')
        if name == 'dog':
                print('Well done')
        else:
         print('Sorry this is not right')
         rep= 0 
         while rep < 5:
                  n()
         rep = rep + 1
         if rep == 5:
              print ('You have guessed incorrectly 5 times.)
```

When i run this and get the answer wrong, the program keeps repeating instead of repeating a maximum of 5 times.

Any ideas?

Comment: The recursive call starts over from 0.  You never get to a second iteration of the while loop.

Comment: `if` is not a loop; it's a branching statement.

Answer (score 2):

What an awkward recursion. :)

The problem is that the `rep` variable is locally scoped, that is, not passed to the recursive call.

You should put the `while` outside and use a `success` variable with the `while` in order to test whether you need to loop again.

No recursion needed.

EDIT:
Like this:

```
def n():
    rep= 0 
    success = 0
    while rep < 5 or success == 1:
        name = input('What is the missing animal?')
        if name == 'dog':
            success = 1
        else:
            print('Sorry this is not right')
            rep = rep + 1
    if rep == 5:
        print ('You have guessed incorrectly 5 times.')
    elif success == 1:
        print('Well done')
```

Sorry for indentation.

Comment: I have tried putting the while loop outside however, when I do that, and i guess the right animal, it keeps asking me what the missing animal is. @Victor

Comment: That's exactly why you have to check for `success` as well. You could also use `break` as in Zach's answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
def n():
    for rep in range(5):
        name = input('What is the missing animal?')
        if name == 'dog':
            print('Well done')
            break
        else:
            print('Sorry this is not right')
    else:
        print ('You have guessed incorrectly 5 times.')
```

Since you know how many times you want to go through the loop, a **for** is (perhaps) more appropriate.  The **else** clause for the **for** loop handles the case where you finish without getting the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You keep calling the n() method over and over within the else statement. I believe this code will work for what you desire:

```
def n():
    rep= 0
    while rep < 5:
        name = input('What is the missing animal? ')
        if name == 'dog':
            print('Well done')
            break
        else:
            print('Sorry this is not right')
        rep = rep + 1
    if rep >= 5:
        print ('You have guessed incorrectly 5 times.')
```

This runs the loop 5 times, unless you get the answer correct. If the answer is correct, the loop will `break`, meaning it stops running. At the end, it checks if rep is greater than (which it never will be) or equal to (which occurs on the 5th loop) and prints the ending message if it has looped 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to recurse. Although this is tail recursive, so I would unwrap it into a loop like @Prune myself.

```
def n(rep=0):
    if n >= 5:
        print ('You have guessed incorrectly 5 times.')
    else:
        name = input('What is the missing animal?')
        if name == 'dog':
            print('Well done')
        else:
            n(rep+1)
```